# VS2008 C++ debugger seems unable/unwilling to look inside instances of structs defined within a function. How are people debugging such code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, nested-class

VS2008 C++ debugger seems unable/unwilling to look inside instances of structs defined within a function when these instances (or references to) are declared in a different scope to the one where the nested struct is defined (such as a for loop). Any idea as to why this is?

```
void MyClass::doSomething()
{
    struct NestedStruct
    {
        int usefulMetaInfo
        vector<double> data;
    };

    //WORKS - Debugger can see inside ns
    NestedStruct ns;
    ns.data.push_back(1);

    //FAILS - Debugger cannot see inside ns
    for{int i=0;i<1;i++}
    {
        NestedStruct ns;
        ns.data.push_back(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's both wrong and unhelpful

Comment: So you have some kind of evidence that most people do write code like that?

Comment: Works just fine on my copy of VS2008SP1, as expected.  Pretty undiagnosable from the provided info.

Comment: Thanks Hans, glad to hear this can work. What additional info would you need to see, in order to try to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I should perhaps mention that the MyClass with the nested struct is defined in a static library VS project that a separate VS dll project uses to link into. I am debugging by attaching to MS software (Excel) that calls this dll (xll actually). Not sure this is relevant as to why I can't get it to work and why you seem to be able to just fine, but will try with a simple as setup as possible myself and come back to you

Comment: @Hans, I just managed to make this work too by putting the nested struct inside a different class. Still need to figure out what is different about what I have done and what is in the code I am debugging. Will come back...

Comment: ok, it seems that the debugger has the problem when an instance (or reference to) the nested struct is declared inside a different scope than the one in which the struct is defined. For example a for loop inside the member function MyClass::doSOmething(). I will amend the question to reflect this

Comment: Down vote. Care to comment why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround to this problem is simple enough.

Just ensure that all handles to NestedStruct are declared within the same scope as NestedStruct's definition. Note that this may often require the use of pointer handles rather than references (when you wish to iterate over a container of NestedStruct for example).

```
void MyClass::doSomething()
{
    struct NestedStruct
    {
        int usefulMetaInfo
        vector<double> data;
    };

    NestedStruct ns*; //declare here
    for{int i=0;i<1;i++}
    {
        //NestedStruct ns*; //DON'T declare here
        ns = someContainer[i];
        ns->data.push_back(1);
    }

}
```

This will allow you to encapsulate the struct neatly where it belongs (implementation detail) while still be able to inspect it using the VS2008 debugger. You give away a bit of control over scope, but it's the best of the available evils.

Why the debugger has this issue I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

Such structs have internal linkage, and almost certainly the debugger has trouble viewing it for the same reason it's illegal to use them as template type parameters.

Your only solution here might be to put the struct into for example a detail namespace to give it external linkage.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'd up vote you if I had the rep. Waiting to see what other answers people may come up with before I accept.

Comment: @Mark.B, have a look at the workaround in my answer, in light of it, I think this is a VS2008 bug/limitation.